# Dynamic routing in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I wanted to convert my website old URL's to new URL's and
here is my old URL's and routing code:-

```
1) www.mysite.com/physics/basics-of-physics 
2) www.mysite.com/physics/what-is-newtons-first-law-in-physics
3) www.mysite.com/chemistry/basics-of-chemistry
4) www.mysite.com/biology/basics-of-biology
```

Below is the routing code I am using for the above URLs is:-

```
$route['physics/(:any)'] = "Physics/index/$1";
$route['chemistry/(:any)'] = "Chemistry/index/$1";
$route['biology/(:any)'] = "Biology/index/$1";
```

And here is new(actual) url's

```
1) www.mysite.com/basics-of-physics  
2) www.mysite.com/what-is-newtons-first-law-in-physics  
3) www.mysite.com/basics-of-chemistry   
4) www.mysite.com/basics-of-biology
```

The simple logic I am using here is,

**1st and 2nd** URL's data stored in **tbl_physics** table and I am using **Physics.php** as a controller.

**3rd** URL data stored in **tbl_chemistry** table and I am using **Chemistry.php** as a controller.

**4th** URL data stored in **tbl_physics** database table and I am using **Biology.php** as a controller.

Here is the code what I tried

```
$route['(:any)'] = "Physics/index/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "Chemistry/index/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "Biology/index/$1";
```

But all the URLs are pointing to the Biology.php controller. 
What modifications do I need to do in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

The var `$route` is an array. You have assigned three different values to the array key `'(:any)'`. Naturally, the value of `$route['(:any)']` will be the last value assigned, i.e. `"Biology/index/$1"`. That is why the `Biology` controller is always used.

You can use regular expressions to define route rules. ([See this](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#regular-expressions))
That's what you need to explore in order to define distinct routes for each URL you have in mind.